# How can you split such complex strings

Tags: c

**INPUT** :

A string in c that looks like this : "    12345      computer seince 101"

***OUTPUT***:

NUMBER OF COURSE = "12345"

NAME OF COURSE = "computer seince 101"

i need to ignore all spacebars before the number and the name, so strings like : "(spaces)12345(more spaces)computer sience 101" are allowded

i tried messing around with strtok, but i failed

Comment: Here the [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function would work wonderfully. It not only convert the initial number in the string to an actual integer, it also tells you where the number in the string ends which means you could copy that part into a second string (or print out directly from that position (plus one to skip the space)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strtol()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3p.html) function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   char str[30] = " 12345 computer science 101";
   char *ptr;
   long ret;

   ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
   printf("NUMBER OF COURSE %ld\n", ret);
   printf("NAME OF COURSE %s", ptr);

   return(0);
}
```

The output is:

```
NUMBER OF COURSE 12345
NAME OF COURSE  computer science 101
```